# Hiera concatenated lookup from yaml

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to configure the puppet-logstash module via Hiera. When I make the call to `hiera('profiles::logstash::config')`, the return value is a concatenated string. It tells me that it cannot convert a String into a hash.

**shipper.pp**

```
class profiles::logstash::shipper() {

  $shipper_config = hiera('profiles::logstash::config')

  notice("${shipper_config}")
  class { 'logstash':
    ensure  => 'present',
    version => '1.4.1-1_bd507eb',
    status  => 'enabled',
  }

  profiles::logstash::config { $shipper_config: }

  include logstash
}
```

**hostname.yaml**

```
classes:
  - os::repo
  - profiles::logstash::shipper

profiles::logstash::config:
  - {content: this is a test, order: 10}
```

Output when used with `notice()`:

`order10contentthis is a test`

Did I order my YAML wrong?

Comment: Copy and pasting the exact error message might be useful.  The first line of the `profiles::logstash::config` class would also be useful to see. Why are you doing an explicity hiera() lookup anyway?  Why not just let the [auto-paramater-lookup](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup) function?

Comment: @Zoredache: Because the auto lookup wasn't populating my define. The error message is also in my post.

Comment: You are mistaken. The concatenation happens when you use the variable in a string context. Puppet coerces hash into a string representation. That is what you are observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `hash_extract` logic by a simple

```
$logstash_configs = hiera('profiles::logstash::config_settings')
create_resource('profiles::logstash::config',$logstash_configs)
```

(minus the `notify` resources, those will need to move into the defined type `profiles::logstash::config`.)

To make this work, the value must use the desired resource title as a key in the nested hash:

```
profiles::logstash::config_settings:
  shipper:
    content: 'this is a test'
    order: '10'
```

The `config_array` is obsolete then.

Note that `hiera_hash` is only needed if you wish to merge hash values from several hierarchy levels. Hash values should normally be retrieved using plain `hiera` calls.